# How to automatically go to the next level?

Tags: clicker-heroes

I have seen people on **Twitch** switching to the next level of Clicker Heroes when they are AFK.

I would really want to have this feature as I think that it is quite troublesome to click to the next stage every time I finish it.

**Do I need to type a code? Please include it if I need one.**

I am playing on the [Clicker Heroes original website](http://www.clickerheroes.com).

Comment: Check the right side of screen for a button. It is there on steam. IDK about web

Comment: @ardaozkal Aside from bein updated later than the web sometimes, the Steam Version is identical to the web version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to beat Level 100 one time in order to get this feature unlocked, then you will find this feature on the right side of the screen:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: red is probably the worst color to draw that arrow

Comment: @ardaozkal happy?

Comment: Should also note that if you're on the steam version; you need to leave the game open for progression mode to work.  If you close out of it; you'll stay on the current level

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness not until I post my beefy build.

Comment: @JimB Has nothing to do with the question. The question is about how to unlock the button, not if you advance offline. That would have to be a different question.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness it's reasonable to assume that this is the goal, and so it would be helpful to include this information and it certainly would not hurt. Since the purpose of the site is to be helpful to future visitors, I feel that including it would make the answer better.

Answer (score -3):

You need to beat lvl 100 and then a boot with wings will show up at the right side of your screen.  you can click it for auto advance.  It works while afk and while your on.

Comment: You're saying exactly what's already said in the accepted answer. Why do you do this?